# Sum (least upper bound) of infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have to find sum (or the least upper bound) of infinite series (exact expression not decimal number) of series $\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{k!(1+k)^k}{(k^2)!}
\end{equation}$. I am clueless, thank you for any help.

Comment: Where is $n$ in your sum?

Comment: 100 terms gives 3.751058201775122658119... No apparent pattern emerging as far as I can tell

Comment: What about 1000? I suspect it's going to be within $+0.1$ of your value.

Comment: @NimaBavari I'll write a program to calculate it. I'll need the program to cancel out as much of the denominator as possible... $(1000^2)!$ is a pretty large number for standard floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Instead, use the upper bound that I showed in my answer, its complexity is far less than computing factorial.

Comment: @NimaBavari A wise idea. I'll calculate both if I can.

Comment: @Pls2 Your sum is an infinite (and convergent) series, not a partial sums. That's why it's independent of any variable.

Answer (score 2):

Stirling formula gives

$$\frac {k! (1 + k)^k} {(k^2)!} < k^{2k - k^2 - \frac {1} {2}} e^{k^2 - k + 1 + \frac {k - 1} {12 k^2}}.$$

Comment: This is very nice!

Comment: @user276387 Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NimaBavari Mathematica estimates of this bound for $n$ terms are: $100: 44.55596381508841697933243577901742083327083106230589993948784728799415152911753...$

Comment: $10$ terms: $44.555963815088416979332435779017420833270831062305899939448843541340243425608551$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen the sum or the sequence?

Comment: @NimaBavari the sum. It appears $10$ and $100$ terms differ very little, on the order of $3.9 \times 10^{-56}$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I had told you! Thanks for the good news.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32903/discussion-between-brevan-ellefsen-and-nima-bavari).

Answer (score 0):

These series $\sum_n a_n$ has a general term $a_n$ that decay extremely fast
for example

$a_1=2$

$a_1=0.75$

$a_3=0.0010582$

$a_4=7.16922\times10^{-10}$

$a_5=6.01578\times10^{-20}$

$a_6=2.27712\times10^{-34}$

Therefore the main contribution to the sum is by the first terms.

$$\sum _{k=1}^{2} \frac{(k+1)^k k!}{k^2!}\approx 2.75$$
$$\sum _{k=1}^{10} \frac{(k+1)^k k!}{k^2!}\approx 2.75106$$
$$\sum _{k=1}^{50} \frac{(k+1)^k k!}{k^2!}\approx 2.75106$$